# unable to check in or see files in source control explorer

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, visual-studio-2015, azure-devops

I am using Visual Studio 2015 professional, our source control is on Visual Studio Team Services. I can make the initial connection to our server, but when I'm trying to check in changes I get

```
"TF400324: Team Foundation services are not available from server"
```

Also, when I'm trying to view files in the Source Control Explorer after a minute or so it writes "Working..." it writes at the tab its disconnected. When my colleague tried to connect from her computer everything was fine, I was also able to connect with my own credentials from a remote machine. Things I've tried:

- deleting files from the TFS cache
- updating Visual Studio from update 2 to update 3
- installing windows updates
- disabling my antivirus
- logging in with a different account
- restarting my computer and renewing my ip

I'm both lost and losing it. Any help would be highly appreciated.
 Thanks

Comment: It sound like missing license. Check what user you at connecting with in the Manage Connection dialog.

Comment: Forgot to mention, also checked that. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, restarting my router helped fixed it. that is very strange because the internet was working fine (I could post a question for SO for example) except I had some issues with Skype. I guess something in that pleased the god of version controls or something.

Comment: I have to wait 2 days. Another new SO rule that I don't understand